Laravel Fortify - error listing routes, expects StatefulGuard, RequestGuard given
I'm installing Laravel's Fortify, when I use php artisan route:list I get the following error
 Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\RegisteredUserController::__construct(): Argument #1 ($guard) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard, Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard given

  at vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers/RegisteredUserController.php:30

I use sanctum as the driver for my API authentication and the 'api' guard
My auth.php config file
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

My fortify.php config file
    'guard' => 'api',
    'middleware' => ['api'],
    'views' => false,
    'features' => [
        // Features::registration(),
        // Features::resetPasswords(),
        // Features::emailVerification(),
        // Features::updateProfileInformation(),
        // Features::updatePasswords(),
        Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
            'confirm' => true,
            // 'confirmPassword' => true,
            // 'window' => 0,
        ]),
    ],


Which version of laravel you are using??

@Subha laravel 10

Set 'guard' => 'web', to both of your fortify.php & auth.php file to ensure that guard is an implementation of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard.For more information check the link to get crystal clear idea https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#authentication-guard . Let me know if you still have issue.

@Subha thanks, it doesn't break anymore, but every fortify route I try to call it gives me Unauthenticated

Can you please print the exact error that you are getting ?

#message: "Unauthenticated."
#code: 0
#file: "
/home/phgrund/.dev/vixtecnologia/docstage-backend/vendor
/laravel/framework/
src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php"
#line: 95
#guards: array:1 [
0 => "web"
]

Okay there are two issue. 1) you are getting AuthenticationException error 2) potential reason could be that your route is not middleware protected or there might be some issue related to auth guard configuration.Check each scenario.
